# Visual Studio not adding the header file to the Solution explorer

Tags: unreal-4, visual-studio

I'm having trouble with my Unreal Visual Studio 2019 project.  I created a new header file, and saved it in the same folder my other ones are in.  (I didn't add these, they were in the starter project of the video course I'm following.) For some reason, the file is not showing in the solution explorer, and IntelliSense isn't working in the particular file.  How do i fix this?  sorry if it's obvious, I'm not an expert at Visual Studio.

Comment: You can regenerate your project files, using your_game_name.uproject file and rmb click: "Generate Visual Studio project files" will add any file you created in your source folder to VStudio solution explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, I needed to add it to the project.

Comment: This answer would be better if it described the steps a user needs to take to "add it to the project".